# Return value from last the copy of recursive function when converting n-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, post, recursion

I cant figure out how to convert n-array like this

```
Array ( 
[Country] => Array (
    [id]    => Array ( [49699]  => Array ( [3]      => 3 ) ) 
    [name]  => Array ( [0]      => Array ( [253]    => Italy ) ) 
    ) 
)
```

where number of keys and just one value, to something like that

```
Array ( 
[Country] => Array (
    [0] => Array( [name] => id,   [flags] => 49699, [type] => 3,   [value] => 3), 
    [1] => Array( [name] => name, [flags] => 0,     [type] => 253, [value] => Italy), 
    ) 
)
```

I have tried to write a recursive function but deeply stuck at the begining.

```
function getPost($post) {

    function _traverse($elem, $cnt, $res) {

           // known structure of keys - value
        $names = Array('name', 'flags', 'type', 'value');

        if(!is_array($elem)) {
            $res[$names[$cnt]] = $elem;
            $cnt = 0;
        } else {
            $k = key($elem);
            $v = $elem[$k];
            $res[$names[$cnt]] = $k;
            _traverse($v, ++$cnt, $res);
            return $res;
        }
    echo '<br/>';
    print_r($res); // last copy of function give what i want
    } 

    $res = Array(); // new array to save result

    $table = key($post); // 1st key
    $arr = $post[$table]; // 1st element 
    $res = _traverse($arr, 0, $res);

    echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
    print_r($res); // give res from first copy

}
```

Unfortunately, after several hours of headache I did not come up with anything better. Could somebody save me, please. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE. So I ended up here

```
function getPost($post) {

    function _traverse($elem, $cnt, $res) {
        $names = Array('name', 'flags', 'type', 'value');
        if(is_array($elem)) {
            $k = key($elem);
            $v = $elem[$k];
            $res[$names[$cnt]] = $k;
            $res = _traverse($v, ++$cnt, $res); 
        } else {
            $res[$names[$cnt]] = $elem;
        }
    return $res;
    } 

    $fields = Array();
    $table = key($post);
    $arr = $post[$table];
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        $fields[] = _traverse(Array($key => $val), 0, Array());
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: It seems I need $res = _traverse($v, ++$cnt, $res); instead of _traverse($v, ++$cnt, $res); return $res;

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array( 
 "country" =>array(
   "id"=> array ( 49699=> array ( 3=> 3 ) ), 
   "name"=> array( 0=> array ( 253=> Italy ) ) 
   ) 
); // input array
$country = $test['country']; // pull countries

$new = array(); // building array

foreach($country as $key => $array) { // first array with keys "name", "id"
 $i = array(); // create temp array to store values
 $i['name'] = $key;

 foreach($array as $key2 => $array2) { // second array with keys 49699, 0
  $i['flags'] = $key2;

  foreach($array2 as $key3 => $value) { // last array with keys 3, 253
    $i['type'] = $key3;
    $i['value'] = $value;
  }
 }

 $new['country'][] = $i; // add new deminsion to building array
}

print_r($new);
```

result will be:

```
Array ( 
 [country] => Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [name] => id [flags] => 49699 [type] => 3 [value] => 3 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [name] => name [flags] => 0 [type] => 253 [value] => Italy )
 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what about if the number of keys will be changed? I just want a function to map names from known structure of array to compilled form data in $_POST n-array.

Comment: number of keys change like how? give an example ?